# HTTP status code 419 when accessing Laravel api by browser

Tags: php, laravel, api

I can't access my laravel api post routes at localhost by browser (script / console / dev-tools). I'm always getting HTTP 419 (Page Expired) status error. Interestingly I can access the api with success via postman.

The routes are outside of everey "auth:sanctum" group, so that this should not be the cause of failure. Because of this I also think that sessions and session config could not be the cause, could they?

```
// routes/api.php
Route::post('/test', function() {
    return "Hello World @ POST";
}); // => HTTP 419

Route::get('/test', function() {
    return "Hello World @ GET";
}); // => HTTP 200
```

I excluded the path from xsrf-checks, to exclude this error cause:

```
// VerifyCsrfToken.php
protected $except = [
    'api/test',
];
```

The script I run in firefox console:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/test", {
    "method": "POST"
});
```

The HTTP request firefox sends to localhost:

```
POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Content-Length: 0
```

What can I do to get my api running in the browser?

**EDIT#1**

app/http/kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        
        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please show your app\Http\Kernel.php

Comment: Odd, VerifyCsrfToken isn't on your api middleware list, so it shouldn't affect it, as far as I know.

Comment: try clearing route-cache! `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @iamab.in Unfortunately did not help

Comment: Yeah, the middleware for the API Group should automatically exclude CSRF checking; it's expected to be accessible from external references. Have you tried with a REST Client like Postman? You _should_ be able to do a POST to that URL without issue: Like this: [`routes/api.php`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoEOE.png), [PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIq2J.png)

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, tried postman and it works fine. Thats what makes it seem very weird to me

Comment: Remove `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` from the api, it's adding the VerifyCSRFToken middleware. Unless you're using Sanctum to authenticate an SPA, it's not needed

Comment: @aynber You got it! Thanks a lot, you have driven away my long lasting headaches. Thanks also to the rest of you for thinking about this problem!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` which parent class is the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`
has this code at its handle method:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (
            $this->isReading($request) ||
            $this->runningUnitTests() ||
            $this->inExceptArray($request) ||
            $this->tokensMatch($request)
        ) {
            return tap($next($request), function ($response) use ($request) {
                if ($this->shouldAddXsrfTokenCookie()) {
                    $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $response);
                }
            });
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException('CSRF token mismatch.');
    }
```

The first check on that big `if` is `$this->isReading($request)`. That method is in charge of checking the request method you're using, and if you see its implementation:

```php
/**
     * Determine if the HTTP request uses a ‘read’ verb.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isReading($request)
    {
        return in_array($request->method(), ['HEAD', 'GET', 'OPTIONS']);
    }
```

So I guess no more words needed.

Here you should ask yourself why they left out the `POST` method.

If you're too sure about this, you can overwrite that method at the `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];

    protected function isReading($request): bool
    {
        return in_array($request->method(), ['HEAD', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST']);
    }
}
```

You can start reading [this](https://laravel-news.com/using-sanctum-to-authenticate-a-react-spa)

Answer (score -1):

1. Accessing from browser url `post` route won't work. Unless you do it via form

```html
<form action="/api/test" method="POST">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

- possible to wire it via a button/link that will submit the form hidden behind the scene

In other words, from What I am seeing you should be able to access:

- GET /api/test (browser url, browser form and postman)
- POST /api/test (browser form, postman)

Comment: Route is `/api/test`, not just `/test`; When adding a route to `routes/api.php`, it auto-prefixes it with `/api/` 

Comment: API routes really aren't meant for forms. They are meant more for javascript and non-HTML functions

Comment: @aynber I agree. This is more to give an example of how to access it not to say we should access api this way.

Comment: It's useful information, but I don't think this quite answers the question; with this, they would still hit a 419 from executing this form `POST` to `/api/test`; I think aynber has outlined the main issue in the comments.